# Deleting a Student in a student array

Tags: java, arrays

I cannot figure out how to delete a student in my student array. I need to continue the array with no gaps or breaks and i am having some trouble doing that. I am also having issues setting the information into the array when adding a student. I can ask for the information but saving it to the array I cant figure out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayDemo
{
static Student[] students;

private static void ViewStudents() 
{

    for( int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println( i + ") " + students[i].getLName() + ", " + students[i].getFName() );
    }
}

private static void ViewDetails()
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );

    int i;
    System.out.println( "Who would you like to view?");ViewStudents();
    i = Integer.parseInt( kb.nextLine() );

    System.out.println( "ANum:\t\t" + students[i].getANum() );
    System.out.println( "\nAddress:\t" + students[i].address.getHouseNum() + " " + students[i].address.getStreet());
    System.out.println( "\t\t" + students[i].address.getCity() + ", " + students[i].address.getState() + " " + students[i].address.getZip());
    System.out.println( "\t\t" + students[i].address.getLine2());
}

private static void AddStudent()
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );

    Student student = new Student();

    String FirstName;
    String LastName;
    int HouseNum ;
    String Street;
    String City  ;
    String State ;
    int Zip      ;
    String Line2 ;

    /* System.out.println( "\tFirst:" + student.getFName() + "\n\tLast:" + student.getLName() + "\n\tA-Number:" +student.getANum()); */

    System.out.println( "\tInput Information" );
    System.out.println( "\tFirst Name:");
            FirstName = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println( "\tLast Name:");
            LastName = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println( "\tHouse Number:");
            HouseNum = Integer.parseInt( kb.nextLine() );
    System.out.println( "\tStreet:");
            Street = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println( "\tCity:");
            City = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println( "\tState:");
            State = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println( "\tZip Code:");
            Zip = Integer.parseInt( kb.nextLine() );
    System.out.println( "\tExtra Information:");
            Line2 = kb.nextLine();

    System.out.println( "\nStudent:\t" + LastName + ", " + FirstName );
    System.out.println( "ANum:\t\t" + student.getANum() );
    System.out.println( "Address:\t" + HouseNum + " " +Street);
    System.out.println( "\t\t" + City + ", " + State + " " + Zip);
    System.out.println( "\t\t" + Line2);

    //students.setAddress( HouseNum, Street, City, State, Zip, Line2 );
    System.out.println( "\tYour Student was Successfully Added" ); 
}

private static void RemoveStudent()
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );
    int i;
    System.out.println( "Who would you like to remove?");ViewStudents();
    i = Integer.parseInt( kb.nextLine() );

    for( i < student.length - 1; i++)
    { students[i] = students[i + 1];
      students[students.length - 1] = null;
     }

public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );

    int x = 40;
    //students = new Student[0];
    students = new Student[2];

    students[0] = new Student( "Thomas","Emily");
    students[1] = new Student( "Bob", "Joe");
    students[0].address = new Address( 6614, "White Sands ln", "Hixson", "Tennessee", 37343, "" );
    students[1].address = new Address( 66, "White  ln", "Hson", "Tealamabaee", 373873, "" );
    do
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println( "Do you want to:"  );
        System.out.println( "\t0) View Students" );
        System.out.println( "\t1) View Students' Details" );
        System.out.println( "\t2) Add a Student" );
        System.out.println( "\t3) Remove a Student" );
        System.out.println( "\t4) Exit" );
        x = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());


        switch (x) 
        {

            case 0: 
                ViewStudents();
                break;
            case 1: 
                ViewDetails();
                break;
            case 2:
                AddStudent();
                break;
            case 3:
                RemoveStudent();
                break;
            case 4: 

                break; 
            default: 
        }
    }
    while( x != 4);

}
```

}

Student.java

import java.util.Random;

public class Student
{

```
Address address; //javac will now compile Address.java

// List private data first -- it's polite to my programmer-user.
private String LName;   // Last Name
private String FName;   // First Name
private int ANum;       // A number

public Student()
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    LName = "";
    FName = "";
    // ANum  =  0;
    ANum = rand.nextInt( 99999999 );
}

public Student( String ln, String fn/*, int an*/ )
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    LName = ln;
    FName = fn;
    // ANum  = an;
    ANum = rand.nextInt( 99999999 );
}

public boolean setLName( String ln )
{
    LName = ln;
    return true;
}

public String getLName()
{
    return LName;
}

public boolean setFName( String fn )
{
    FName = fn;
    return true;
}

public String getFName()
{
    return FName;
}

// public boolean setANum( int an )
// {
    // ANum = an;
    // return true;
// }

public String getANum()
{
    // String str = String.format( "A%08d", ANum );
    // return "A" + ANum;
    // return str;
    return String.format( "A%08d", ANum );
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the problem happening and what do you expect?

Comment: Think of an array as a pile of books, when you remove one from any position, the other books have to come down, so this means you need to `rotate` every book from the removed book position up to the end. This will prevent you from having holes or breaks in your array.

Comment: Does this have to be done using Array structure? An easier and efficient way to do so would be having a Map<String, Student> where String is string representation of student (or some hash that uniquely identifies student, even an index like you used might suffice). Then adding would be equivalent to inserting into the Map and deletion would be equivalent of removing from the Map. This is efficient especially if the maps is HashMap.

Comment: By removing do you mean reallocation space for the array? Or just putting its value to `null`? Reallocation is a pain. That is why tools such as `List` and `Map` were invented.

Comment: I mean removing it all together from the array

Comment: Again, reallocation or setting it to null? It is a difference. Setting it to null it still takes up space for a reference and the size would still be the same.

Comment: Reallocation in that case. I need it to be renumbered in the array after one is deleted.

Comment: You can read this http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/ArrayReallocation.htm To find out exactly how. I took a quick glance and it looked correct. If you still are having problems, get back here and show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList<E>` is your friend here. With this, you can add and remove elements, with the gaps filling up automatically. Need `import java.util.ArrayList<E>;`

```
ArrayList<Student> = new ArrayList();
```

Ensures a size of 10, which can be accessed with the `size()` method. `add(E e)` will allow you to append to the list, and `remove(Object o)` or `remove(int i)` lets you remove either a specific index or a specific instance of type E.

Alternatively, shifting everything away could do the trick

Given an array of type `Foo`, say you want to remove the object at index 3.

```
for(int i = 3; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
arr[arr.length - 1] = null;
```

To add an object(still an array of type foo),

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] == null) { 
        arr[i] = bar;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible with this solution to not get a null error when looking back at the ViewStudents.    How would I add it to the next empty space?

Comment: 1: just use `if(arr[i] == null) break;` since you wouldn't have any nulls in the middle. 2: just keep iterating through until you hit an empty space. Please consult most recent edit

Answer (score 1):

When I see the word `student`, it appears to me that this is a school work. Thus, I wouldn't ask you to use anything more than array.

**To delete a record in an array:**

In array, if you want to delete a record with no gaps in-between, you have to "shift up" the records behind one by one. This is the only way to close a gap in array. (without using any other data structures).

```
//record of student, index to be deleted, number of records you have
public static int deleteRecord(Student[] record, int idx, int numOfRecords)   
{
    if(idx < 0 || idx > numOfRecords) //Check index is valid
        return -1;

    for(int x=idx; x<numOfRecords; x++) //closing the gap by copying the next value
        record[x] = record[x+1];

    return (--numOfRecords);
}
```

**To add a record in an array:**

1. Check whether the limit for number of records has been reached.
2. If still have space for more, add at the **last** available slot.

Adding a student record:

```
public static int addRecord(Student[] record, int numOfRecords)   
{
    if(numOfRecords >= record.legnth) //Check record is not full yet
        return -1;

    //prompt for student particulars
    record[numOfRecords].name = xxx;   //where xxx is input by user
    record[numOfRecords].id = yyy;   //where yyy is input by user
    return (++numOfRecords);
}
```

I've seen many university/college having this kind of assignment. They normally expect you to keep track of the number of records you currently have.

Because you didn't post how your Student class looks like. If you have a static variable in Class Student recording the number of students objects added. You don't have to manually keep track of number of records. It will look like this if you have a counter in your Student class:

```
public class Student
{
    static int numOfRecords = 0;
    public Student()
    {
        numOfRecords++;        
    }      
}
```

---

To maintain what you currently have, add one more static variable outside your main. (It looks like your don't want to pass anything to the methods)

```
static int numOfRecords = 0; //declare outside your main

public static void AddStudent()
{
    Scanner scn = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.println("Enter last name:");
    String ln = scn.nextLine():
    System.out.println("Enter first name:");
    String fn = scn.nextLine():

    Student stud = new Student(ln, fn);
    students[numOfRecords] = stud;
    numOfRecords ++;
}
```

That's all you need to add.

Comment: It is. How would I go about doing that in this particular case?

Comment: Give me several minutes, I will give you a complete solution for both. Typing out now..

Comment: @EmilyThomas If you are allowed to use ArrayList, it is a better choice than array.

Comment: @Emz The only thing I am not following the syntax is on receiving user input. I am sure OP knows how. Other than that, I am following the conventions. By the way, you `need not` use brackets for one liners, especially when providing a solution here. It makes your code harder to be interpreted. Especially from a beginner.

Comment: Further more, it is impossible to provide OP a complete solution. Firstly, OP didn't provide a complete implementation of Student class, secondly this is his/her homework. Thirdly providing a complete solution may affect other parts of his/her code which OP already implemented.

Comment: Please see my AddStudent method. How would I add that user given information to the the array?

Comment: @EmilyThomas I need to know what's in your Student class first.

Comment: I will post it in an edit

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test
{
    static Student[] students = new Student[3];

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        students[0] = new Student ("Thomas");
        students[1] = new Student ("Bob");
        students[2] = new Student ("Mark");

        removeStudent(1);

        for (Student s : students) {
            System.out.println(s.getName());
        }

    }

    public static void removeStudent (int index) {
        // valid index
        if (index < 0 || index > students.length) {
            return;
        }

        // null it
        students[index] = null;

        // move all elements after index back
        for (int i = index; i < students.length-1; i++) {
            students[index] = students[index+1];
        }

        Student[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(students, students.length-1);
        students = temp;
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version of your code. Student now only has a name with a getter for it. But that removeStudent reallocates the memory for `students`.

Hope you can draw some wisdom from it.