# Adding a Student to an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have figured out how to gather the data from the user to make a new student in my array, but I am having trouble adding that information to the array. Please show me how I can add this data as a new Student object in the given code. Please reference to the `AddStudent` method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayDemo {

    static Student[] students;

    private static void ViewStudents() {

        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ") " + students[i].getLName() + ", " + students[i].getFName());
        }
    }

    private static void ViewDetails() {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i;
        System.out.println("Who would you like to view?");
        ViewStudents();
        i = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
        System.out.println("ANum:\t\t" + students[i].getANum());
        System.out.println("\nAddress:\t" + students[i].address.getHouseNum() + " " + students[i].address.getStreet());
        System.out.println("\t\t" + students[i].address.getCity() + ", " + students[i].address.getState() + " " + students[i].address.getZip());
        System.out.println("\t\t" + students[i].address.getLine2());
    }

    private static void AddStudent() {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        Student student = new Student();

        String FirstName;
        String LastName;
        int HouseNum;
        String Street;
        String City;
        String State;
        int Zip;
        String Line2;

        System.out.println("\tInput Information");
        System.out.println("\tFirst Name:");
        FirstName = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\tLast Name:");
        LastName = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\tHouse Number:");
        HouseNum = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
        System.out.println("\tStreet:");
        Street = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\tCity:");
        City = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\tState:");
        State = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\tZip Code:");
        Zip = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
        System.out.println("\tExtra Information:");
        Line2 = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nStudent:\t" + LastName + ", " + FirstName);
        System.out.println("ANum:\t\t" + student.getANum());
        System.out.println("Address:\t" + HouseNum + " " + Street);
        System.out.println("\t\t" + City + ", " + State + " " + Zip);
        System.out.println("\t\t" + Line2);

        //students.setAddress( HouseNum, Street, City, State, Zip, Line2 );
        System.out.println("\tYour Student was Successfully Added");
    }

    private static void RemoveStudent() {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Who would you like to remove?");
        ViewStudents();

        for (int j = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine()); j < students.length - 1; j++) {
            students[j] = students[j + 1];
        }

        students[students.length - 1] = null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = 40;
        //students = new Student[0];
        students = new Student[2];

        students[0] = new Student("Thomas", "Emily");
        students[1] = new Student("Bob", "Joe");
        students[0].address = new Address(6614, "White Sands ln", "Hixson", "Tennessee", 37343, "");
        students[1].address = new Address(66, "White  ln", "Hson", "Tealamabaee", 373873, "");

        do {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Do you want to:");
            System.out.println("\t0) View Students");
            System.out.println("\t1) View Students' Details");
            System.out.println("\t2) Add a Student");
            System.out.println("\t3) Remove a Student");
            System.out.println("\t4) Exit");
            x = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());

            switch (x) {

                case 0:
                    ViewStudents();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ViewDetails();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    AddStudent();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    RemoveStudent();
                    break;
                case 4:

                    break;
                default:
            }
        } while (x != 4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way without much change to your code would be to add a class variable called index next to the students array. This variable will keep track of the amount of students since [**arrays in Java have fixed length**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

```
 public class ArrayDemo
 {
     static Student[] students;
     static int index = 0;      // keeps track of the amount of students in the students array
     // ... rest of your code
```

Then inside `AddStudent()` you add all the information you got from input to the current student at the index and update the index:

```
private static void AddStudent() {

   // ... the code where you obtain user information

   if(index < students.length) {  // make sure there is room to add the user
       Student student = new Student(/* add user information into the constructor */);
       students[index] = student; // add the user at the index 
       index++;                   // update the index
   } else {
       System.err.println("No more room for students");
   }
}
```

The code above assumes you have a constructor that accepts necessary user information.

Otherwise you can assign the information individually:

```
Student student = new Student();
student.firstName = firstName;
// ...
```

Or use setters like:

```
student.setFirstName(firstName);
```

If you do not with to use an index to keep track of amount of users and have a more dynamic way of storing the students, then I suggest using a [**`List`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or some class that extends it such as an [**`ArrayList`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: I told OP the exact same thing in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414176/deleting-a-student-in-a-student-array/27414517#27414517 He just don't believe us that he need to keep track number of students.

Comment: @user3437460 Minor note; assuming by the OP's name, he = she

Answer (score 1):

Believe me that there is no way you can add records to array without knowing how many records are there currently in your array. If you don't want another static variable to keep track number of records, you have to loop through the array till it is null.

```
static int numOfStudents = 0; //declare outside your main

public static void AddStudent()
{
    Scanner scn = new Scanner( System.in );

    if (numOfStudents < students.length){
        System.out.println("Enter last name:");
        String ln = scn.nextLine():
        System.out.println("Enter first name:");
        String fn = scn.nextLine():

        Student stud = new Student(ln, fn);
        students[numOfStudents] = stud;
        numOfStudents ++;
    }
}
```

An **alternative solution** which you would prefer. But this is bad in my opinion.

```
public static void AddStudent()
{
    Scanner scn = new Scanner( System.in );

    int index=0;

    while(x<students.length && student[x] != null)
        index++; //get position to add new student

    System.out.println("Enter last name:");
    String ln = scn.nextLine():
    System.out.println("Enter first name:");
    String fn = scn.nextLine():

    Student stud = new Student(ln, fn);
    students[index] = stud;      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you are using the wrong kind of data structure. You seem to what to add a dynamic number of `Student`s and an `ArrayList` would be a lot better and more appropriate than an `Array`. Then you can simply use the `add` method.

Remember, the size of an `Array` is immutable (it cannot change) so what you want in this case is definitely some sort of `List`, probably the `ArrayList`

If you insist on using an array, you would need to keep track of the number students already added and use that as an index (either as a global variable or pass it in as a parameter). But bear in mind that the nature of an `Array` means that you will hit a cap very quickly unless you set an very high capacity,

Comment: I cannot use an ArrayList for this code. That would be a lot simpler of course, but it will not be accepted. I am very lost about adding another student to the array

Comment: @EmilyThomas then just do what David said. Use an index to keep track of the amount of students and add students at the index, while there is room in the array. You can check out mine or user3437460's answer for a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Your array has a fixed size of 2 elements. You could instead use a larger MAX value and (as the other answers have hinted) keep a variable that counts the actual number of array indices that are filled.

```
static int ARRAY_MAX = 10;
static Student[] students;
static int numStudents;
...
students = new Student[ARRAY_MAX];
numStudents = 0;
```

Adding a student would then look like...

```
students[numStudents] = new Student();
numStudents++;
```

...but its going to break when numStudents is greater than equal 10 (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException).

In this event you need to enlarge (resize) your array. In Java arrays have fixed size - resizing an array amounts to declaring a brand new array (with increased size), and then copying the old array into the new one. Use System.arraycopy to copy the contents from one array into the other.

You should really just use an ArrayList - behind the scenes this is what that object is doing.